# Command `cargo run` leads to "No such file or directory"

Tags: rust

I need to run tests that run separate processes with `sudo` privilege (as they need to run privileged instructions e.g. [shmat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat)).

I use `.cargo/config` to run tests with `sudo`, this is what causes the error, removing it allows the test to work until it attempts `shmat` at which point it fails.

In a minimal reproducible example the error is:

```
thread 'tests::base' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/lib.rs:4:103
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

The layout of the project is:

```
.
├── .cargo/
│   └── config.toml
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src/
    ├── lib.rs
    └── bin/
        └── new_process.rs
```

`config.toml`:

```rust
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
runner = 'sudo -E'
```

`cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "mre"
version = "0.1.0"
[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.127"
```

`lib.rs`:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn base() {
        let output = std::process::Command::new("cargo").args(["run","--bin","new_process"]).output().unwrap();
        dbg!(output);
    }
}
```

`new_process.rs`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let shmid = libc::shmget(libc::IPC_PRIVATE, 1024*4, libc::IPC_CREAT);
    let shared_mem_ptr = libc::shmat(shmid, std::ptr::null(), 0);
    println!("hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed cargo via [rustup](https://rustup.rs/), it will likely be installed in your home directory, and not globally like in `/usr/bin/`.

On my machine:

```
$ which cargo
/home/linus/.cargo/bin/cargo
```

So under sudo, cargo is not found:

```
$ sudo cargo
sudo: cargo: command not found
```

This is the exact same error you got from `unwrap`ing the result of `Command::new().output()`.
So it is not a rust problem; it's a linux problem.

1. You could specify an absolute path to the cargo executable:

```
// in lib.rs base()

// Modify for the location of cargo on your machine
Command::new("/home/linus/.cargo/bin/cargo")
```

2. Or you could create a symlink from `/usr/bin/cargo` to `/home/linus/.cargo/bin/cargo`:

```
sudo ln -s /home/linus/.cargo/bin/cargo /usr/bin/cargo
```

Then, cargo is also found using sudo.

3. Or you could install cargo globally by using a [standalone installer](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#standalone-installers). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65255288/14350146